# ASP:ListBox Get All Values As Selected Items

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I'm just wondering how can I possibly get all values in a ListBox as selectedItems? Note that the viewed records came from an SQL datasource. I'll be using these values as list of email addresses for an email blast.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.
I'm using ASP.Net C#

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select all items in a listbox control, Use This

```
listView1.MultiSelect = true;
foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items )
{
   item.Selected = true;
}
```

or you can do like this with LINQ :
Just pass your listview and checkstate to the function.

```
public void CheckAllItems(ListView lvw, bool check)
{
    lvw.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().ToList().ForEach(item => item.Checked = check);
}
```

Comment: Hello there,
How can I declare this line of codes in able to use it as a list for example. Please help me, thanks.